# I'm unable to send a post request and get the response back from API

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I'm working on ReactJS technology to learn and grow in web development. I have started working on projects like crud applications. Recently I have created a Catalogue menu which can display display data from an API.

So as the API is a dummy one I was successfully able to fetch the information from it.

Now there was an assignment I was given in which I have to send a post request to the API and get back the response from it.

So I need to send the data after encrypting it with an encryption key for hitting the API and get back the response.

This is the code I have done and I'm not even able to get the error flag message in the console.

I think there is something I might have missed or done wrong with sending the request to API or I'm not correctly console logging the response which I get.

Look into the code I have written for sending the post request to the API to get the response from it once the correctly encrypted parameters are sent if not I have to console the error I'm doing.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import CryptoJS from "crypto-js";

import axios from "axios";

import "./login.css";


function Login() {

  const [mobile, setMobile] = useState("");
  const [pin, setPin] = useState("");
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState("");
  

  const navigate = useNavigate();


  const data = { user_mobile: mobile, user_pin : pin} 

  const ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), 'tpcgkCABsh051409').toString();


  const handleSubmit = async (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted")
    const data = { user_mobile: mobile, user_pin: pin };

    fetch("http://business.thesmartr.com/v1/authorization/login.php", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "access-control-allow-origin" : "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      mode:"no-cors",
      body: ciphertext
    })
    .then(response => response.json)
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error:", error);
      alert(error.message);
    });
  }
  

  return (
    <div className="main-div">
      <div className="center">
        <div className="logo">
          <img src="/images/bizwy logo.svg"/>
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="txt-field">
            <input
                type="number"
                value={mobile}
                onChange={(event) => setMobile(event.target.value)}
                required
              />
              <span></span>
            <label>Mobile Number</label>
          </div>
          <div className="txt-field">
            <input
                type="password"
                value={pin}
                onChange={(event) => setPin(event.target.value)}
                required
              />
              <span></span>
            <label>Password</label>
          </div>
          <div className="pass">Forgot Password</div>
          {/* <button type="submit">Login</button> */}
          <div className="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

I think my mistake is exactly when I'm sending the encrypted values in the body.
Check whether there is anything I have done error while sending the post request or any other error I'm making.

I'm providing the sandbox link for complete code details, if you need anything regarding the code details or the task I have to achieve feel free to ask me.

https://codesandbox.io/s/qr-menu-smvr6h?file=/src/Login.js

Comment: `response.json()`... it's a function

Comment: According to the error, This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. Meaning you should serve the server on https instead of http

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the [json method of the response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json).

```js
// your code
.then(response => response.json)

//what you actually need to do
.then(response => response.json())
```

Comment: I have changed it and now I'm getting the error saying failed to fetch. Is it because of the input I'm sending to the API or do you thing anything might have gone wrong

Comment: Not sure about the api you are trying to call, but the request is blocked by the browser because of mixed content (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content).
That means you are trying to call non SSL endpoint from a secure context. This is blocked by default. However, trying to call the endpoint via https is failing to verify the certificate returned (NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID)